# Making a div element programmatically and vertically scroll within another div element

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I want to showcase a mobile-friendly layout. To do that, I have a page with a big iPhone in it. In the screen area, I want my layout to appear and automatically scroll down vertically then scroll up to initial point.

I found a [vertical carousel](http://www.htmowl.com/blog/jcarousel-vertical-scroll-with-multiple-items/) for that, but I'd like it to be automatic. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question

Comment: Can you scroll to an anchor tag at the bottom of the page then back to one at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't give the code, I made my own prototype. Tweak this code to fit your needs, if you add code I can do it for you. Here is the basic idea.

```
<body style="background: grey;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 800px; background: white; overflow-y: hidden;" id="page">
        <div style="height: 2000px; width: 385px;">
            <div style="background: red; height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <div style="background: blue; height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <div style="background: green; height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <div style="background: yellow; height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <div style="background: purple; height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var page = document.getElementById('page');
        var times = 0;
        window.setInterval(function(){
            times++;
            page.scrollTop = times;
            if(times == 1200){
                window.clearInterval();
            }
        }, 5);
    </script>
</body>
```

If you want it to come back up after completing just add `page.scrollTop = 0` at the end. If you want to run it again set times to 0 and run that interval again by putting it into a function, right after `clearInterval();`.

I hope I helped! If there's something you're not clear about just comment below.

Finished one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALzMJ/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort Marlo! One thing though: there's only one div that should scroll (the one that will feature the mobile-friendly webpage) inside the fixed one (the one that represents the iPhone screen), not several. And the div that scrolls should be taller than the container (iPhone screen)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment. Where there is five divs, you can throw anything you want. The div in the `#page` is the actual page and the `#page` is just the screen. Sorry for complexity. Look the jsfiddle in the answer for better understanding!

Comment: Here's the fully finished product free for use: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALzMJ/3/)

Comment: Hey that's awesome! Exactly what I had in mind, thanks Marlo.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it can get (edited just for the record):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Outer">
    <div id="Inner">
       …
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#Inner {
    margin: 16px 16px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
step = 0;

int_1 = setInterval( function() {
    step++;
    Outer.scrollTop = step;
    if (step >= Outer.offsetHeight+16) {
        clearInterval(int_1);
        setTimeout( function() {
            int_2 = setInterval( function() {
                step--;
                Outer.scrollTop = step;
                if (step <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(int_2);
                }
            }, 5);
        }, 500);
    }
}, 5);
```

JSFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hArP/4/).

Comment: Thanks arielnmz, but the scroll should be programmatically achieved (sorry I realize my question was ambiguous, I edited it)

Comment: That's what the javascript is for.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't move when I view it on my computer.

Comment: It may be a bug, this works for me on chrome 35. Edit: Tried it again, it works.